# How to define vim color highlight region consisting of single line matching certain pattern

Tags: vim

I would like to color each digit in its own color, but only if this digit is part of a "digitmap" and not in a regular text.
In this example, the "DigitMap" region should be any line that possibly starts with " and contains nothing else but digits and spaces. I know how to define region using start and end, but this does not work for large digitmaps.

```
syn region DigitMap start="+++" end="---" contains=m0,m1,m2,m3,m4,m5
syn match m0 "0" contained
syn match m1 "1" contained
syn match m2 "2" contained
syn match m3 "3" contained
syn match m4 "4" contained
syn match m5 "5" contained

hi clr1 guibg=#e41a1c ctermbg=196
hi clr2 guibg=#377eb8 ctermbg=68
hi clr3 guibg=#4daf4a ctermbg=77
hi clr4 guibg=#984ea3 ctermbg=133
hi clr5 guibg=#ff7f00 ctermbg=208
hi clr6 guibg=#ffff33 ctermbg=227

hi def link m0 clr1
hi def link m1 clr2
hi def link m2 clr3
hi def link m3 clr4
hi def link m4 clr5
hi def link m5 clr6
" +++
" 003300311111041000000000011000000200011112103333312233433333311222222010000000
" 123332300000041303111122211200001200011102103333311033443000211111115015210001
" 123332311021041333333222211233331200020133133333210033444423211111105015210001
" 123332322021041333333222221212400200020222220222200033444423211112105555510000
" 003112344444444322222222100002445002222222240112201033401011111332105555412211
" 213002311144442222222222111014445502222220044444400033400000011332555550444311
" 111111300003002000022222123312355222222221240444101030000000111330020350410311
" ---
```

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you want - are you looking for a regexp that will match that possibly starts with " and contains nothing else but digits and spaces? If so, this `"\?\s\+\d\+` highlights all the lines between the " +++ and " --- lines in what you posted

Comment: @mattb, I need to highlight individual digits, but only withing the lines that match that pattern

Comment: hmm, then unfortunately I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not work for large digitmaps"? The code seems to work with your example.

Comment: @j1-lee, there seems to be a limit of how many lines ahead (or behind) vim looks when it detects a region. For example if digitmap is 50 lines long and you scroll couple of screens beyond its bottom end and then move up until lower part begins appearing in view, then these lines will not be colored.

Comment: I see your point. How about adding `syntax sync minlines=N` where `N` is a sufficiently large number? `:help syn-sync-minlines`